# Decay Function with some additional features

Tags: exponential-function

I'm writing a computer function to model data which seems to slope down exponentially until it gets to an optimal point. At that point it steadily grows and then stabilizes. What type of function would create this type of graph?

Maybe using a step function utilizing more than 1 function is a good solution?

[image: A decay curve with a little upward slope which stabilizes]

Comment: If it has to be polynomial an odd power might work (ie x^3, x^5).  If you can use a difference equation (recurrent), a second order should work.